# Is this a group homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism, quotient-group

**Problem**: Define $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ by the natural projection $\pi \, : \, \mathbb{Q} \longrightarrow \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, where $\pi(x) = \text{frac}(x) = x - \lfloor x \rfloor$ for all $x \in \mathbb{Q}$.  Show that $\pi$ is a homomorphism.

**Question**:  Is $\pi$ really a homomorphism by this definition?

$$\pi\left(\frac{5}{3} + \frac{7}{4}\right) = \pi\left(\frac{41}{12}\right) = \frac{41}{12} - \left \lfloor \frac{41}{12}\right \rfloor = \frac{41}{12} - 3 = \frac{5}{12}$$

but

$$\pi\left(\frac{5}{3}\right) + \pi\left(\frac{7}{4}\right) = \left[\frac{5}{3} - \left \lfloor \frac{5}{3}\right \rfloor\right] +  \left[\frac{7}{4} - \left \lfloor \frac{7}{4}\right \rfloor\right] = \left[\frac{5}{3} - 1\right] +  \left[\frac{7}{4} - 1\right] = \frac{2}{3} + \frac{3}{4} = \frac{17}{12}.$$

Comment: $\dfrac5{12}$ and $\dfrac{17}{12}$ are different representatives of the same element in the quotient group

Comment: To get $\pi(x)$ in $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$, I think you actually want $\pi(x)=x-\lfloor x\rfloor + \mathbb Z$

Comment: What you forgot is that the addition on $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is defined by $x\oplus y = \mathrm{frac}(x+y)$ So your computaion of $\pi(5/3)+\pi(7/4)$ should have beein \mathrm{frac}((2/3)+(3/4)) = \mathrm{frac}(17/12) = 5/12$.

Comment: What do you think is the addition in $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$? How do you add $\frac{2}{3}$ and $\frac{3}{4}$, **in $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$**? Remember that it’s a group, so the sum of two things in $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ must be a thing in $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. Either you describe the elements of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ as cosets (which you are not doing), or else you define addition properly, which you have not done. It’s not a question of agreeing or disgreeing, It’s a question of defining things correctly, and you are not doing so.

Comment: It’s the same issue as in $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$. If you want to describe the elements of the quotient as $0,1,2,3,4$, then the addition there is not the addition of integers, it’s the “addition modulo $5$’, so that the sum of $3$ with itself is not $3+3$, it’s $(3+3)-5$. You define addition there by saying that the sum of $a$ and $b$ is $a+b$ **if** $a+b\lt 5$, and is $a+b-5$ otherwise. The same thing in $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. If you represent elements as naked rationals (not cosets), then the definition of addition needs to be adjusted.

Comment: @CqXMVYdXgTgHX8u58jTghk I'm thinking that you aren't actually confused about this, but are just looking to score points against your instructor on a detail.

Comment: Are you actually asking a question, or looking for a fight? Because it looks like the latter. If you want to represent $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ as the set $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$, then you define the projection by $\pi(k) = \text{the remainder of dividing }k\text{ by }5$. But more importantly, **by definition of the quotient**, if you are using representatives for the cosets, then the definition of the operation in the quotient is that $a\oplus b$ is “the representative of the coset to which $a+b$ belongs”. There may be many ways of writing that as a formula, but the operation in the quotient is not +

Comment: So in $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, the way you add $\pi(r)$ and $\pi(s)$ is not to just add $r$ and $s$ as if they were rationals and *stop*, it’s “find the unique representative that is equivalent to $r+s$ among your selected set of representatives, and that’s the answer.” You can describe that multiple ways, but it’s the sum in the quotient, not the sum in $\mathbb{Q}$. You computed the sum in $\mathbb{Q}$, so you were doing the wrong operation to the objects you had.

Comment: Do you understand that to define a group you need a set and an operation? The definition of $\pi$, given explicitly, describes explicitly what the set is. Saying that it is “the canonical projection” defines the operation implicitly: it defines it by saying that two add two representatives, you find the representative that corresponds to their sum in the original group. If you define $\pi(k)$ as the remainder of dividing $k$ modulo $5$, you are saying, explicitly, that the set is $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$, and you are saying, implicitly, that addition is “add, then find the representative of the sum”.

Comment: And the problem (which is somewhat easy, but something beginners should do) is to verify that if you define addition that way on the image set, then the function you started with actually gives you a group homomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

This is a homomorphism.  Another way of expressing the map is by the rule $x\mapsto x+\Bbb Z$.

$\Bbb Z\triangleleft\Bbb Q$, so the quotient $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$ is a group.

$π$ is the canonical projection onto the quotient by a normal subgroup, which is always a homomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{5}{12} = \frac{17}{12}$$

in $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: The image of the coimage of the map is $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. It may be sloppy notation, but identifying an element of a quotient with a select representative is extremely common and not something to get hung up on.